# CSS image replacement without pop-in preserving transformations

Tags: jquery, html, css, sprite

brothers and sisters in code! I'm trying to change the background of an element on a hover state but I'm having issues with pop-in on the hover.  I'm curious as to how I might pre-load the hover state version of this image in the background specifically using jquery, maybe using .load.

I have taken a look at the usual solutions given for this problem and the go to answer seems to be sprites. However, I'm doing some css animations and transforms that I'm satisfied with and can't easily think of a way to do so with sprites--maybe you can.

So, it would be a big help to have some guidance on one of these methods (or another more ingenious one).  Below is my code, a jsfiddle, and the makings of a sprite for good measure. Thank you all very much!

**http://jsfiddle.net/3RMZB/**

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-wrap">
    <header class="header" id="header" role="banner">
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
background-image: url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-low-color-clear.png");
transition: 0.5s;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left;
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
}

#header-wrap:hover #header {
background-image: url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-full-color-clear.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
width: 700px;
-webkit-transform: rotateX( -7deg ) rotateY( -5deg );
-moz-transform: rotateX( -7deg ) rotateY( -5deg );
-o-transform: rotateX(-7deg ) rotateY( -5deg );
transform: rotateX( -7deg ) rotateY( -5 deg );
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
-moz-transform-origin: center center;
transform-origin: center center;
-webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
-moz-transition-duration: .3s;
transition-duration: .3s;
-webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
-moz-transition-delay: .1s;
transition-delay: .1s;
}
```

**[Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbryi.png)**

Comment: PS - I absolutely HATE that you have a transition delay.  I'm way too impatient for that.

Comment: Check the new new down below for some goodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Deryck had the right idea with "Option 1" -- load both images in the default state -- but the wrong way of executing it.  If you over-write the background image declaration, you're telling the browser not to use the previous image, so it doesn't download.

What you *can* do is use layered backgrounds to load both background images in the default state, with the coloured version hidden behind the desaturated one.  It wouldn't work if the two images didn't line up perfectly, but they do, so this should be what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/3RMZB/1/

```
#header {
background-image: 
   url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-low-color-clear.png"), 
   url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-full-color-clear.png");
/* ... */
}

#header-wrap:hover #header {
background-image: 
   url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-full-color-clear.png");
/* ... */
}
```

Comment: By the way, if your only concern with the sprites was that you didn't want a sliding effect on the transition, remember that you can specify which properties a CSS transition applies to.  So you can transition the angle but have the shift in background position be instantaneous:  http://jsfiddle.net/3RMZB/2/ (you'll need to finesse @Deryck's sprite file, of course, so you don't get that slight shift in position when switching between the desaturated and coloured versions).

Comment: This technique works--great! Thank you AmeliaBR! (and @Deryck for the alley-oop). Now, I'm going to press my luck and ask for more, I guess. Outside of jsFiddle (e.g. the actual implementation) both images load in side-by-side (so to speak) when they first load in staggered segments with the colored image loading slightly before the overlaying grayed-out image.  It kinda ruins the surprise of there being a colored active version because you see the color version loading under it. Any ideas on what to do for this? Please let me know if I'm not explaining this clearly.

Comment: On the sprites solution @AmeliaBR, my problem is I can't think of a way to preserve the illusion of a color transition from the reduced saturation version to the fully saturated version.

Comment: I see what you mean about the transition, once I slowed it down.  Hadn't noticed that the conversion between backgrounds was being nicely animated before.  Okay, two files it is.

Comment: On the file load order, I suppose you could create a third state: the basic state would have just the desaturated image, so it starts loading first; then (since you're using JQuery anyway) add a class to the body when the webpage has finished loading everything, and use that to trigger the layered background images state, so it starts downloading the second file. You'd still get a download delay if the user hovers before both files have finished downloading, but you can't really do anything to prevent that.

Comment: With a sprite *and* a pretty transition, thanks to using a single-transparent-pixel data URI as a replacement for the disappearing image layer.  http://jsfiddle.net/3RMZB/5/  (Although note that Firefox doesn't transition background images like Chrome does).  One day, people won't use ancient IE versions and we'll be able to do all of this with [filters](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/xGuBr).

Comment: I went with a variation of your jquery clean up suggestion, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

## Preferred method - Sprites

Because of the transitions, the hover on `#header` needs to be separated from that of `#header-wrap` unless you actually want the cool image scroll effect.

### [What you want](http://jsfiddle.net/X5NVK/)

### [What you could have](http://jsfiddle.net/MZz2C/)

### [What I would do if I were you for coolness](http://jsfiddle.net/XwWm2/)

### CSS (what you want)

```
#header {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbryi.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
}
#header:hover {
    background-position: top right;
}
#header-wrap, #header-wrap:hover {
    -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .1s;
    transition-delay: .1s;
}
#header-wrap:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-7deg) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-7deg) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-7deg) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: rotateX(-7deg) rotateY(-5 deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -moz-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
```

---

*Other options*

## Option 1:

Just put both bg-images in the default state, making sure the non-active one is first so it gets over-ridden.  They will both be loaded and only the normal one will show at first.  Then when you hover, it goes for the cached image.

### [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bC62m/)

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-image: url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-full-color-clear.png");
    background-image: url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-low-color-clear.png");
...
}
#header-wrap:hover #header {
    background-image: url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-full-color-clear.png");
...
}
```

---

## Option 2:

Use `opacity` instead of two different files.

### [Different fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp5ar/)

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-image: url("http://edgarbounds.net/sites/default/files/header-full-color-clear.png");
    opacity: .25;
...
#header-wrap:hover #header {
    opacity: 1;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Deryck. Option 1 sounds great, but sadly doesn't work for me (try clearing your cache before using your fiddle?).  Option 2 is a possibility but changing the opacity is not exactly the same look that I'm going for; I'm hoping to preserve the look exactly.  Thanks again.

Comment: *Spites* as I understand the technique as used to prevent pop-in is by loading a single image in a viewing pane of set dimensions and then modifying background position. I don't see how this will method will allow me to keep all my transitions as they are.  Feel free to correct if necessary as that might be something that would unlock the riddle.

Comment: Yeah sorry I made the comment about the sprites because the fiddle you have in your post shows you loading two separate images instead of loading the sprite.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'd upvote you for effort if I had the ability to do so already, but your Spites methods do not preserve the illusion of a color transition from the reduced saturation version to the fully saturated version. I can't figure how to do that with a moving background image. So close but no cigar--not to be picky here but you'd understand if it were your design and in context. ;)